# How to remove/disable new background-image transition in image style?

Tags: html, css, userscripts

So, there is sudden addition to all images in all browsers for all people I know. Probably some kind of new update or standard, whatever. I don't know **what** it is and **why** it is.

But from now on, when You enter any image there is this thing:

```html
<img style="
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
        transition: background-color 300ms;"
        src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/light/light_PNG14421.png
">
```

I'm specifically saying about `background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%)` and `transition: background-color 300ms;`. In Firefox it looks like instead of Transition, there is just static white background. FOR NO REASON. You can't really see the difference in images that doesn't have transparent background, but if You directly open any kind of png image that does have alpha channel it suddenly have white backgronud.

Like `http://pngimg.com/uploads/light/light_PNG14421.png`
[image]

this for example.

I tried to find out how to disable it, but I don't know why there is such background in a first place. So suddenly. I open images im browser to compare them so very often and it really annoys me, that now I can't do that. Anyone knows where it come from? Is there some sudden change in some CSS or HTML standards? Is it Windows thing? (However Android 11 does the same thing on Opera Touch...) or what?

And can I just remove **any** transition effects in img style by using something like Tampermonkey? If so, how can I do that?

To clarify... I want only background-color (and optionally transition) to remove. I've seen scripts that can remove whole div if the div containts something. But I don't want to remove img if the style contain anything. Just the remove the annoying style, which is unnecessary.

Thanks in advance. I tried to make the script myself from what i found in Google, but it's few days already and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information for a proper answer, therefore the answer will be general.

**Find the image/s**
You would need some criteria to pinpoint the correct images, like id, class, etc
I used `src` in this example

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('img[src^="http://pngimg.com/uploads/"]');
```

**Loop through images and make changes**

```js
images.forEach(img => {
  img.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';  // change to whatever desired
  img.style.transitionProperty = 'none';      // change to whatever desired
}):
```

#### Alternative Methods

With above UserScript changes are made at the time script runs. If images are created dynamically & later, then addition code is needed to wait for the change and apply/reapply the changes.

You can also use UserScript to insert CSS. CSS rules are applied to all images present and those that are created dynamically later.

Here is an example ....

```js
const css = `
img[src^="http://pngimg.com/uploads/"] {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  transition-property: none !important;
}`;

GM_addStyle(css); // TamperMoneky | ViolentMonkey | FireMonkey
// or 
GM.addStyle(css); // GreaseMonkey | TamperMoneky | ViolentMonkey | FireMonkey
```

You can also use UserStyle/UserCSS (Stylish | Stylus | xStyle | FireMonkey) to achieve similar outcome. Using UserStyle/UserCSS has lower overheads in comparison to UserScript.

Here is an example of UserStyle. You would need to set the matching URLs in the UserStyle controls.

```css
img[src^="http://pngimg.com/uploads/"] {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  transition-property: none !important;
}
```

Here is an example of FireMonkey UserCSS

```css
/*
==UserCSS==
@name           Change Background
@match          .... the site to match
==/UserCSS==
*/

img[src^="http://pngimg.com/uploads/"] {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  transition-property: none !important;
}
```

---

### Update on Comment

> It's opening the image itself (right click and "Open image in new tab").

I see.... here are some examples.

- Tested on `http://pngimg.com/uploads/light/light_PNG14421.png` with Firefox 87.0a1
- Based on URLs ending in `.png`

**FireMonkey UserCSS**

```css
/*
==UserCSS==
@name           Remove Image background
@match          *://*/*.png
@run-at         document-start
==/UserCSS==
*/

img {
  background: transparent !important;
}
```

**UserScript with any manager** (GreaseMonkey | TamperMoneky | ViolentMonkey | FireMonkey)

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Remove Image background
// @match         *://*/*.png
// @run-at        document-start
// @grant         GM.addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

GM.addStyle('img {background: transparent !important;}');
```

**UserScript with TM | VM | FM** (using legacy `GM_addStyle` with TamperMoneky | ViolentMonkey | FireMonkey)

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Remove Image background
// @match         *://*/*.png
// @run-at        document-start
// @grant         GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle('img {background: transparent !important;}');
```

**UserScript without GM functions**

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Remove Image background
// @match         *://*/*.png
// @run-at        document-start
// ==/UserScript==

(() => {

const style = document.createElement('style');
style.textContent = 'img {background: transparent !important;}';
(document.head || document.body).appendChild(style);

})();
```

**Note**

If `file:///` processing is required, then add

```js
// @match         file:///*.png
```

Comment: There is literally no id or class, because it's just any image (local or not) that is opened by browser. It's just how any browser adds the CSS (but some do that differently, namely Firefox doesn't add transition, just static background). If I have cat.png on my desktop and open that file in Opera, Chrome, Vivaldi, Edge, Firefox or any other browser that exist, it has pre-made CSS to display the image. But for few days all browsers are adding white background to image (and that's the style I included in my original question). This wasn't the case before. Images had no style added by browsers.

Comment: Also, I am a little confused. First code You posted, it's Tampermonkey script? When I try to add it, the script editor shows error, that const is reserved. When I tried to change it to var, is says that > in another line is unexpected and so on. What I wanted is that if I open any image (no matter where is it from), the script just remove background and transition from that image. I can do that manually too by inspecting element and disabling the part of code. But I would like something that dos that automatically. If You try to open img I posted in my first post, You can see white background.

Comment: @KitsuneChan The script is for any script-manager but it is not complete. It is a snippet. `const` is reserved error is due to TM ESLint set to old JS standard. Are you opening the image on its own? Not in a web page?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing. It's not image on web site. It's opening the image itself (right click and "Open image in new tab"). I'm using Opera as image viewer sometimes, because it lets me compare multiple files and is quicker than downloading image and opening it in Windows. That's why there is no class or id. It's literally image on its own. Also it doesn't need to be userscript, anything that would just change the new... whatever it is, standard or not. Because when it automatically adds background to image, it's really annoying. And I don't even know WHY was that change made.

Comment: @KitsuneChan ... I have updated the post based on your comment.

Comment: So... the Opera sent "'Remove Image background' failed! GM.addStyle is not a function" error in the console. But I managed to google out the solution. I had to change dot to underscore and because it told be then, that GM_addStyle is undefined, I had to define it myself. Thanks for all the help! Now it completely works. Without Your help I would never figure it out. Thanks so much!

Comment: @KitsuneChan ... I have updated the post based on your comment, for info.

Comment: There is one more thing. The info for the people, that would potentially use this script. It works very fine, but to make it work also with local files, I had to let Tameprmonkey to have access to file URLs. So if anyone find this, I hope they find the solution of their problems too :)